# custom jquery slider right/left arrows cause loop to mess up

Tags: jquery, slider

I built this slider [www.freewaycreative.com/jsfun/](http://www.freewaycreative.com/jsfun/)

There are four slides but the fourth is the same image as the first (which just sits in the back while 2-4 slide in then get pushed back into their hidden position.

My problem arises with the direction arrows. I have 4 different IDs for each left and right arrows so they can appear at specific z-indexes so I can differentiate the slides based on what arrows appear. when I hover over a slide, a specific set of arrows will appear.

when I click an arrow I want it to slide in the next slide. but it completely confuses the script. I basically want it to do what the nivo slider does. check it out.

Answer (score 0):

Your link seems to be broken (as I can't access the example you're explaining). From the sounds of it, a jQuery gallery / carousel would be an ideal solution to what you're looking to do... Have a look at jCarousel - it's a very flexible content/image carousel and would work quite nicely in your scenario.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need all of those arrows.  Just one left and one right.  You can figure out all the rest with js and jquery.

Here is a simple version I put together:

http://jsfiddle.net/jtbowden/ZR9bM/

It's not perfect, but it is much simpler.  The problem you were having is that every time the arrow was clicked, you started a new animation loop through a bunch of `setTimeout`s.  You needed to stop your existing timeout before you started another one.  In my script, I store the timeout, or interval in this case, in a variable, and then call clearInterval (or clearTimeout) to stop it.

Of course, I could also ask... if you like Nivo, why not just use Nivo?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you. I fiddled with what you made and got it to work. I had to remove the clearinterval from the hover function and add it to the click functions, then restart the automatic slider after the single slide.

However, is it swinging? the reason i dont want nivo is because it doesnt swing. Also, I am trying to learn to write my own stuff. But it looks as if our new slider is no longer swinging. At least not as much as my original slider.

The same function is used in both versions:
 animate({ "left": "-=800px" }, 1000);

Why do they behave differently?
Thanks again

link: http://jsfiddle.net/ZR9bM/14/

Comment: Actually, I checked jQuery UI 1.8.9 and now I think its swinging. Ive been staring at it so long I cant even tell anymore. Is there an easy way to make is swing harder?

Comment: What do you mean "swing harder"?  What do you want it to look like?  BTW, I had the clearInterval in the hover just so it wouldn't slide at all while you were manually navigating.  If you were slowly clicking through the slides, it would be annoying if the slide slide back after you had slid it the other way.  So, as long as your mouse was in the container, it would pause the sliding.

Comment: P.S.  It is better practice to comment or edit your question, instead of adding another "answer".  Please make sure to accept my answer (or a better one), as it increases the likelihood that others will answer future questions.

Comment: Cant seem to check your answer as accepted. isnt there supposed to be a blank check mark? im using the easing plugin to get a good swing to the slides. for some reason, just linking jquery-ui wasnt making the animate() function swing the images across, or it was too subtle to notice. heres the code freewaycreative/jsfun/fiddle.html

Comment: I moved the clearIntervals around so that it paused the loop on mouseover, and restarted the loop when  you mouseout and after you click on an arrow. It works ok now except if you mouseover then mouseout, you have to wait 5 seconds for the loop to start up again. Maybe if i timed the hover, and if it was over five seconds, the loop would fire up immediately on mouseout. is it possible to time a hover?